# Can those squares form an imperfect square

Tags: code-golf, math, number, geometry, decision-problem

Given a non-empty array of positive integers, determine if it is possible to take squares with side lengths specified by each integer, and arrange them in space such that they form a square.

The output can have anything as truthy / falsey values, and the input array may contain duplicates.

For the truthy testcase `[3,2,2,2,1,1,1,1]`, a possible way to arrange the square is:

```
aaabb
aaabb
aaaef
ccddg
ccddh
```

where each letter represents a different square. The lengths of the squares are completely specified by the given array.

Numberphile did a [video](https://youtu.be/NoRjwZomUK0) on that which inspired me to write this challenge. He called this an imperfect square. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code wins.

### Testcases

Truthy:

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
[3,2,2,2,1,1,1,1]
[12,11,11,7,5,5,4,3,3,2,2,1,1]
```

Falsy:

```
[2,1]
[2,2,2]
[3,4]
```

Comment: Please add test cases.

Comment: This one is about square nor a rectangle, but it's a similar thing.

Comment: I have edited two of your truthy testcases because they were wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I worked both of them out by hand and did some mistakes as i typed them in.

Comment: I thought this was as easy as checking all the ints in the array squared equalled a square number till I saw the `[3,4]` test case.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder This was the exact why I added it...

Comment: Is this about the new Numberphile video??? yes, it is...

Comment: You saw nothing

Comment: I did the same, @TheLethalCoder and now I can't see past that to figure out what the actual solution might be!